# How to set index of pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have tried to choose a column to be an index of a data frame. The examples I've seen so far suggests to use the method set_index(), but it doesn't work in my case. I use python 3.7.0

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit' : ['Apples','Oranges'],
                   'Amount': [ 1, 17 ]})

df.set_index('Fruit')


print(df1)
```

The output that I get is

```
       Fruit  Amount
0   'Apples'       1
1  'Oranges'      17
```

The output I want would be something like

```
              Amount
     Fruit  
    'Apples'       1
   'Oranges'      17
```

Comment: `df = df.set_index('Fruit')`

Comment: or `df.set_index('Fruit', inplace=True)`

Comment: {inplace=True} makes the difference! Thank you!